# How to add own validation message for accepts_nested_attributes_for?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-attributes

I have these 2 models:

**users**

```
has_one :additional_data, :dependent => :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :additional_data
```

**additional_data**

```
belongs_to :user
validates :skype, :presence => {:message => 'cannot be blank.'}
```

and form:

```
<%= form_for@user do |f| %>
  <p>
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :email %>
  </p>
  <%= f.fields_for :additional_data do |ad| %>
        <p>
          <%= ad.label :skype, "Skype" %><br />
          <%= ad.text_field :skype %>
        </p>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

If I send empty form, the message about missing Skype data is not displayed. What am I missing?

Also, I would like to ask you, if I can according value in variable in URL validate the `additional_data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Rails won't display inline errors.

You can either use a plugin like [simple form](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form) which I recommend, or display the errors at the beginning of the form by iterating over `@user.errors.full_messages`.

Comment: above the form is the area, where are printed out the error messages. The problem is, that the error message about missing Skype contact is not printed out. If I will dump `@user.errors.full_messages`, so there is not the message for missing Skype...

Comment: Is `additional_data_attributes` in your list of accessible attributes? (attr_accessible :additional_data)?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [validates_associated](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated).  It validates whether the associated object or objects are all valid themselves.

```
# user.rb
has_one :additional_data, :dependent => :destroy

validates_associated :additional_data

accepts_nested_attributes_for :additional_data
```